# Is there a way to set up GitHub copilot in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, github-copilot

I am using free versions of both. I have searched GitHub documentation but I couldn't find any reference to google Colaboratory.

Answer (score 13):

Well, I guess there is a way. But don't expect it to be easy.
Thing is, copilot is avaliable for VSCode.
And you can use VSCode with Colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/JayThibs/jacques-blog/blob/master/_notebooks/2021-09-27-connect-to-colab-from-local-vscode.ipynb#scrollTo=Lh1y3R5ta948

If you'll get to the bottom of this it would be interesting to read about your experience.

Answer (score 4):

You can try https://codesquire.ai/. It uses the same OpenAI codex for code completion and it comes with a Chrome extension so that it's usable in Colab

Answer (score 2):

I found [Codeium](https://codeium.com/) autocompletion to be of better quality than CodeSquire. At least it is another good option. It has a Chrome extension, too.

Comment: And it has instructions on how to use it in google collab over here: https://codeium.com/chrome_tutorial